# How to convert heading of file content into column using awk?

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I am trying to convert heading of file content into column using awk, below is my input file -

```
abc.txt
1234|43245
4325|65123
5432|12342
bcd.txt
865|432
324|543
123|654
cde.txt
12|321
21|123
32|123
```

output :

```
abc.txt|1234|43245
abc.txt|4325|65123
abc.txt|5432|12342

bcd.txt|865|432
bcd.txt|324|543
bcd.txt|123|654

cde.txt|12|321
cde.txt|21|123
cde.txt|32|123
```

Explanation :
Fetch the filename(abc.txt) where `NR==1` and put it into an array `a` or variable and print it will the file contents and when the file contents are completed create a blank line.

I was trying to create two array `a` one for `NF=1` and another array `b` for `NF>1` and loop on array `b` to merge file content with array `a` but still trying to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NF==1{h=$0} {print (NF==1?"": h OFS $0)}' file

abc.txt|1234|43245
abc.txt|4325|65123
abc.txt|5432|12342

bcd.txt|865|432
bcd.txt|324|543
bcd.txt|123|654

cde.txt|12|321
cde.txt|21|123
cde.txt|32|123
```

Downside is, that it prints an empty line in the beginning. If you can't live with that, add `NR==1{next}` before the `print`ing block - or better yet: see [@EdMorton's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669125/how-to-convert-heading-of-file-content-into-column-using-awk/42669813?noredirect=1#comment72479634_42669813) below.

Explained:

```
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }                # set delimiters
NF==1{ h=$0 }                      # if NF==1 it's header time, store it to h
# NR==1{ next }                    # to remove the leading enter, apply this
{ print (NF==1 ? "" : h OFS $0) }  # print an empty record or the record with header
```

Comment: Instead of suggesting `...add NR==1{next} before the printing block.` just add an `NR>1` condition to your printing block: `NR>1{print (NF==1?"": h OFS $0)}`.

Answer (score 1):

So here is my solution:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{ OFS = "|"} /[a-z].[a-z]/{ if ($0 != header && NR > 1){print ""}; header = $0 }/[0-9]\|[0-9]/{ numbers = $0; print header, numbers }' yourfile
```

Output:

```
abc.txt|1234|43245
abc.txt|4325|65123
abc.txt|5432|12342

bcd.txt|865|432
bcd.txt|324|543
bcd.txt|123|654

cde.txt|12|321
cde.txt|21|123
cde.txt|32|123
```

It is without any arrays but it seems to work.

Comment: there are 2 linebreaks instead of one

Comment: I know, wrote that I' am aware of that and try to solve it.

Comment: @JFS31 - Verified, Thanks for your Answer.

Comment: @VIPIN KUMAR you need an explanation or is everything clear?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `awk` approach:

```
awk '{ if($1~/[a-z]+.txt/) { if(NR != 1) {print ""} h=$1;next } print h"|"$1;}' testfile
```

The output:

```
abc.txt|1234|43245
abc.txt|4325|65123
abc.txt|5432|12342

bcd.txt|865|432
bcd.txt|324|543
bcd.txt|123|654

cde.txt|12|321
cde.txt|21|123
cde.txt|32|123
```

---

*Explanation:*

`if($1~/[a-z]+.txt/)` - the condition checks if current column `$1` matches the pattern `/[a-z]+.txt/`(header column)

`h=$1;next` - if a column matching the pattern is found, saves *header* value e.g. `abc.txt` into variable `h` and skips a *header* line via `next`

`if(NR != 1) {print ""}` - prints a linebreak if it's not the first occurance of a *header* line

`print h"|"$1;` - prints a *header* value with a separator and each next *subsequent* line

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F '|' '{if(NF==2)$0=F"|"$0;else{F=$1;$0=""}}NR>1' YourFile
```

self commented:

```
# use | as separator
awk -F '|' '
  # for every lines
     {
     # line with "data" have 2 field
     if(NF==2) {
        # add File nameand  "|"  in front of current line
        $0 = F"|"$0
        }
      else {
        # File name is field 1
        F=$1
        # change line to empty line
        $0=""
        }
      }
   #print line (in new state, ater 1st line), default action of a trigger
   NR>1  
   ' YourFile
```

Comment: For test case - if we change the header with footer then which part we need to change in the existing code?
e.g.,

`1234|43245
4325|65123
5432|12342
abc.txt`

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR Changing header to footer means complete rewrite of the script—all of these scripts actually—to buffer the records until the footer is found then construct, output and delete the buffered records, rinse and repeat.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR, James Brown sing it like a charm. Another way is to pre-reorder by reading the file in reverse order before comming to awk. Reingeneering the code will use a buffer before printing until file name is know

Comment: Agreed but for the test case (later Req.) I tried below trick - 
tac file.txt | awk {...code...} |tac
it worked fine.